How can I display a PDF in an Expo Go project?
I’m working on a React Native project using Expo Go, and I need to display PDF files within the app.
I’ve looked into using libraries like react-native-pdf, rn-pdf-reader-js and react-native-file-viewer, but it seems they require custom native code, which Expo Go doesn’t support.
Is there a way to show PDF files in Expo Go without ejecting or using native modules?
Ideally, I want to keep the PDF viewer within the app itself (so no external browser or in-app browser please). If anyone has suggestions or alternatives that work within Expo Go, I’d really appreciate it!

rn-pdf-reader-js shouldn't need anymore what Expo Go provides but you have to likely fork it in order to get the dependencies working.

@ArchimedesTrajano I took a look at rn-pdf-reader-js and reuse the code inside it to create a new functional component: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79139193/11918620

One approach is to use a WebView to show the PDF.
The following code provides a way to load PDFs via URLs or base64 encoding. The solution is built with TypeScript and functional components, and the styles and functionality are fully customizable.
It works entirely within Expo Go, without requiring any custom native modules!
I used the following libraries (all supported in Expo Go):

expo-file-system (version ~17.0.1)
react-native-webview (version 13.8.6)

And obviously:

react (version 18.2.0)
react-native (version 0.74.5)
expo (version ~51.0.28)

import * as CSS from "csstype";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Platform, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import {
  WebViewErrorEvent,
  WebViewHttpErrorEvent,
  WebViewNavigationEvent,
  WebViewSource,
} from "react-native-webview/lib/WebViewTypes";

const {
  cacheDirectory,
  writeAsStringAsync,
  deleteAsync,
  getInfoAsync,
  EncodingType,
} = FileSystem;

export type RenderType =
  | "DIRECT_URL"
  | "DIRECT_BASE64"
  | "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF"
  | "URL_TO_BASE64"
  | "GOOGLE_READER"
  | "GOOGLE_DRIVE_VIEWER";

export interface CustomStyle {
  readerContainer?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerDocument?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerNumbers?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerNumbersContent?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerZoomContainer?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerZoomContainerButton?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerNavigate?: CSS.Properties;
  readerContainerNavigateArrow?: CSS.Properties;
}

export interface Source {
  uri?: string;
  base64?: string;
  headers?: { [key: string]: string };
}

export interface Props {
  source: Source;
  style?: View["props"]["style"];
  webviewStyle?: WebView["props"]["style"];
  webviewProps?: WebView["props"];
  noLoader?: boolean;
  customStyle?: CustomStyle;
  useGoogleDriveViewer?: boolean;
  useGoogleReader?: boolean;
  withScroll?: boolean;
  withPinchZoom?: boolean;
  maximumPinchZoomScale?: number;
  onLoad?: (event: WebViewNavigationEvent) => void;
  onLoadEnd?: (event: WebViewNavigationEvent | WebViewErrorEvent) => void;
  onError?: (event: WebViewErrorEvent | WebViewHttpErrorEvent | string) => void;
}

const originWhitelist = [
  "http://*",
  "https://*",
  "file://*",
  "data:*",
  "content:*",
];

const htmlPath = `${cacheDirectory}index.html`;
const pdfPath = `${cacheDirectory}file.pdf`;

async function writePDFAsync(base64: string) {
  await writeAsStringAsync(
    pdfPath,
    base64.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", ""),
    { encoding: EncodingType.Base64 }
  );
}

export async function removeFilesAsync(): Promise<void> {
  const { exists: htmlPathExist } = await getInfoAsync(htmlPath);
  if (htmlPathExist) {
    await deleteAsync(htmlPath, { idempotent: true });
  }

  const { exists: pdfPathExist } = await getInfoAsync(pdfPath);
  if (pdfPathExist) {
    await deleteAsync(pdfPath, { idempotent: true });
  }
}

const getGoogleReaderUrl = (url: string) =>
  `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${url}`;
const getGoogleDriveUrl = (url: string) =>
  `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=${url}`;

const Loader = () => (
  <View
    style={{
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
    }}
  >
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
  </View>
);

const validate = ({
  onError,
  renderType,
  source,
}: {
  onError: (event: WebViewErrorEvent | WebViewHttpErrorEvent | string) => void;
  renderType: RenderType;
  source: Source;
}) => {
  if (!renderType || !source) {
    onError("source is undefined");
  } else if (
    (renderType === "DIRECT_URL" ||
      renderType === "GOOGLE_READER" ||
      renderType === "GOOGLE_DRIVE_VIEWER" ||
      renderType === "URL_TO_BASE64") &&
    (!source.uri ||
      !(
        source.uri.startsWith("http") ||
        source.uri.startsWith("file") ||
        source.uri.startsWith("content")
      ))
  ) {
    onError(
      `source.uri is undefined or not started with http, file or content source.uri = ${source.uri}`
    );
  } else if (
    (renderType === "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF" || renderType === "DIRECT_BASE64") &&
    (!source.base64 ||
      !source.base64.startsWith("data:application/pdf;base64,"))
  ) {
    onError(
      "Base64 is not correct (ie. start with data:application/pdf;base64,)"
    );
  }
};

const init = async ({
  renderType,
  setReady,
  source,
}: {
  renderType?: RenderType;
  setReady: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  source: Source;
}) => {
  try {
    switch (renderType!) {
      case "GOOGLE_DRIVE_VIEWER": {
        break;
      }

      case "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF": {
        await writePDFAsync(source.base64!);
        break;
      }

      default:
        break;
    }

    setReady(true);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const getRenderType = ({
  source,
  useGoogleDriveViewer,
  useGoogleReader,
}: {
  source: Source;
  useGoogleDriveViewer?: boolean;
  useGoogleReader?: boolean;
}) => {
  const { uri, base64 } = source;

  if (useGoogleReader) {
    return "GOOGLE_READER";
  }

  if (useGoogleDriveViewer) {
    return "GOOGLE_DRIVE_VIEWER";
  }

  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    if (uri !== undefined) {
      return "DIRECT_URL";
    }
    if (base64 !== undefined) {
      return "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF";
    }
  }

  if (base64 !== undefined) {
    return "DIRECT_BASE64";
  }

  if (uri !== undefined) {
    return "URL_TO_BASE64";
  }

  return undefined;
};

const getWebviewSource = ({
  source,
  renderType,
  onError,
}: {
  source: Source;
  renderType?: RenderType;
  onError: (event: WebViewErrorEvent | WebViewHttpErrorEvent | string) => void;
}): WebViewSource | undefined => {
  const { uri, headers } = source;

  switch (renderType!) {
    case "GOOGLE_READER":
      return { uri: getGoogleReaderUrl(uri!) };
    case "GOOGLE_DRIVE_VIEWER":
      return { uri: getGoogleDriveUrl(uri || "") };
    case "DIRECT_BASE64":
    case "URL_TO_BASE64":
      return { uri: htmlPath };
    case "DIRECT_URL":
      return { headers, uri: uri! };
    case "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF":
      return { uri: pdfPath };
    default: {
      onError!("Unknown RenderType");
      return undefined;
    }
  }
};

const PdfViewer = ({
  source,
  style,
  webviewStyle,
  webviewProps,
  noLoader = false,
  useGoogleDriveViewer,
  useGoogleReader,
  onLoad,
  onLoadEnd,
  onError = console.error,
}: Props) => {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [renderType, setRenderType] = useState<RenderType | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [renderedOnce, setRenderedOnce] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (renderType) {
      console.debug(renderType);
      validate({ onError, renderType, source });
      init({ renderType, setReady, source });
    }

    return () => {
      if (
        renderType === "DIRECT_BASE64" ||
        renderType === "URL_TO_BASE64" ||
        renderType === "BASE64_TO_LOCAL_PDF"
      ) {
        removeFilesAsync();
      }
    };
  }, [renderType]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (source.uri || source.base64) {
      setReady(false);
      setRenderType(
        getRenderType({ source, useGoogleDriveViewer, useGoogleReader })
      );
    }
  }, [source.uri, source.base64]);

  const sourceToUse = useMemo(() => {
    if (!!onError && renderType && source) {
      return getWebviewSource({ onError, renderType, source });
    }
    return undefined;
  }, [getWebviewSource, onError, renderType, source]);

  const isAndroid = useMemo(() => Platform.OS === "android", [Platform]);

  return ready ? (
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      <WebView
        {...{
          onError,
          onHttpError: onError,
          onLoad: (event) => {
            setRenderedOnce(true);
            if (onLoad) {
              onLoad(event);
            }
          },
          onLoadEnd,
          originWhitelist,
          source: renderedOnce || !isAndroid ? sourceToUse : undefined,
          style: [styles.webview, webviewStyle],
        }}
        allowFileAccess={isAndroid}
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={isAndroid}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={isAndroid}
        scalesPageToFit={Platform.select({ android: false })}
        mixedContentMode={isAndroid ? "always" : undefined}
        sharedCookiesEnabled={false}
        startInLoadingState={!noLoader}
        renderLoading={() => (noLoader ? <View /> : <Loader />)}
        {...webviewProps}
      />
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>{!noLoader && <Loader />}</View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  loaderContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default PdfViewer;



Render Types: This code supports various ways to display PDFs, such as direct URLs, base64, and Google Drive Viewer.
PDF Storage and Cleanup: The writePDFAsync function writes the PDF to
cache for use in the viewer, and removeFilesAsync handles cleanup.
Validation and Initialization: validate checks source validity, and init initializes the rendering based on renderType.
WebView Setup: WebView is used to display the PDF content based on
chosen render type, and Loader provides feedback while loading.

